# How to select row with conditions (multiple records in another table)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. First table is a table with id and attributes describing the id and another table to show the activities for the users. So each user may have a single or multiple activities.

user

```
user_id  server_id  user_name  user_email
00001    10         Tom        tom@email.com
00002    20         Bob        bob@email.com
00003    10         Sid        sid@email.com
```

user_activity

```
user_id  activity_id  activity_date
00001    1            2015-03-15
00002    4            2014-07-27
00001    3            2014-02-09
00003    5            2014-11-22
00003    4            2015-08-18
```

I want to select 1000 users with a condition that it must have multiple rows in user_activity table.

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.user_email FROM user a
INNER JOIN user_activity b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE a.server_id = 10
AND (user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000)
GROUP BY a.user_id 
HAVING COUNT(a.user_id > 1)
LIMIT 1000
```

The query above gives me a mix of users with both single and multiple rows. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
HAVING COUNT(a.user_id > 1)
```

To

```
HAVING COUNT(a.user_id)>1
```

and i think it will give desired output

Comment: Thanks! So it was a syntax error on my end....I must have overlooked the brackets. I tested a few lines and it looks good so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the subquery I applied a COUNT to evaluate if rows are more than 1

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.user_email
FROM user a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT('ACTIVITY')
      FROM user_activity b
      WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id) > 1
AND a.server_id = 10
AND a.user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
LIMIT 1000
```